# how can i upload an image in a collectionType?

Tags: symfony, file-upload, symfony-forms

First of all I would like to thank you for your help and your time. I'm new to coding with symfony.
So if you see things to improve and you want to let me know, I'll take any good comments.
Thank you for your understanding.

I would like to make a recipe that has several steps and each step has a description and an image.
I use a collectionType.
I manage to recover the steps with their descriptions and their images.
but when I flush to send to the database the first image is overwritten since it's in a loop.

everything works correctly until this piece of code I did a var_dump and I recover the images with their name changed

**var_dump($imageFileName2);**

but during the foreach loop where i want to set my image the first one get overwritten

```
  foreach($stepsImgs as $s) {

                   $s->setStepsImage($imageFileName2);

                }
```

*Edit here if this can help you more about it*

```
 foreach($imgs as $im) {
         $imageFileName2 = $fileUploader->upload($im);
         var_dump('<br>HERE ARE THE NAME OF THE IMAGE AFTER THE FILEUPLOAD : '.$imageFileName2.'<br>');
                              
                foreach($stepsImgs as $s) {
                    
                    $s->setStepsImage($imageFileName2);
                
                }      
            }
```

output:
[image]

and at end its the dd before flush

***I let you check my code and again thanks you for your time.***

here you have my Recipe Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\RecipeRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RecipeRepository::class)
 */
class Recipe
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $recipeName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $duration;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=RecipeIngredients::class, mappedBy="recipes", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $recipeIngredients;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $recipeImage;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $recipeDescription;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="recipes")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Difficulty::class, inversedBy="recipes")
     */
    private $difficulty;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Steps::class, mappedBy="recipe", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $steps;


    

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->recipeIngredients = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime('now');
        $this->steps = new ArrayCollection();
       
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRecipeName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->recipeName;
    }

    public function setRecipeName(string $recipeName): self
    {
        $this->recipeName = $recipeName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDuration(): ?int
    {
        return $this->duration;
    }

    public function setDuration(int $duration): self
    {
        $this->duration = $duration;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRecipeImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->recipeImage;
    }

    public function setRecipeImage(?string $recipeImage): self
    {
        $this->recipeImage = $recipeImage;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRecipeDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->recipeDescription;
    }

    public function setRecipeDescription(?string $recipeDescription): self
    {
        $this->recipeDescription = $recipeDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;

       
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return Collection<int, RecipeIngredients>
     */
    public function getRecipeIngredients(): Collection
    {
        return $this->recipeIngredients;
    }

    public function addRecipeIngredient(RecipeIngredients $recipeIngredient): self
    {
        if (!$this->recipeIngredients->contains($recipeIngredient)) {
            $this->recipeIngredients[] = $recipeIngredient;
            $recipeIngredient->setRecipes($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeRecipeIngredient(RecipeIngredients $recipeIngredient): self
    {
        if ($this->recipeIngredients->removeElement($recipeIngredient)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($recipeIngredient->getRecipes() === $this) {
                $recipeIngredient->setRecipes(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

   

    public function getMinuteFromLastUpdate($id)
    {
        // $updateDate = new \DateTime($this->getCreatedAt());

        $updateDate = $this->getCreatedAt();
        $now = new \DateTime('now');

        $calculateDate = $updateDate->diff($now)->format('%H:%i');

        return $calculateDate;
    }

    public function getDifficulty(): ?Difficulty
    {
        return $this->difficulty;
    }

    public function setDifficulty(?Difficulty $difficulty): self
    {
        $this->difficulty = $difficulty;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Steps>
     */
    public function getSteps(): Collection
    {
        return $this->steps;
    }

    public function addStep(Steps $step): self
    {
        if (!$this->steps->contains($step)) {
            $this->steps[] = $step;
            $step->setRecipe($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeStep(Steps $step): self
    {
        if ($this->steps->removeElement($step)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($step->getRecipe() === $this) {
                $step->setRecipe(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

   

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getRecipeName();
    }
  

    
}
```

Here my RecipeController and the method when i want create the recipe :

```
 /**
     * @Route("admin/create/recipe/{id}", name="create_recipe")
     */
    public function createRecipe(Request $request, FileUploader $fileUploader, EntityManagerInterface $em, Category $category=null, Steps $steps=null): Response
    {
        $recipe = new Recipe;

        $form = $this->createForm(RecipeFormType::class, $recipe);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        
        $imgs = [];
        $stepsImgs =[];
        
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $recipe->setCategory($category);

            $imageFile = $form->get('recipeImage')->getData();

            $imageFilesData = $request->files;

            foreach($imageFilesData as $imageFiles) {  
                 
                foreach($imageFiles as $value) {
         
                    foreach($value as $images) {
                       
                        foreach($images as $img){
                          
                            $imgs[] = $img; 
 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach($recipe->getSteps() as $stepImg) {
                
                $stepsImgs[] = $stepImg;
            }

            foreach($imgs as $im) {
                
                $imageFileName2 = $fileUploader->upload($im);
                              
                foreach($stepsImgs as $s) {

                   $s->setStepsImage($imageFileName2);

                }      
            }
   

            if ($imageFile) {
                $imageFileName = $fileUploader->upload($imageFile);
            
                $recipe->setRecipeImage($imageFileName);
            }

            // dd($recipe);
            $em->persist($recipe);
           
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('dashboard', []);
          
        }

        $formView = $form->createView();

        return $this->render('admin/recipe/createRecipe.html.twig', [
            'formView' => $formView,
            'recipe' => $recipe,
            'recipeId' => $recipe->getId(),
        ]); 

    }
```

here my RecipeFormType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Difficulty;
use App\Entity\Recipe;
use App\Form\CategoriesFormType;
use App\Form\RecipeIngredientsFormType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class RecipeFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('recipeName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Name of the recipe',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Type the name of the recipe',
                ],
                
            ])
            
            ->add('recipeImage', FileType::class, [

                'label' => 'Image of the recipe',

                "attr" => ['class' => "form-control"],

                'mapped' => false,

                'required' => false,

                'constraints' => [

                    new File([

                        'maxSize' => '10254k',

                        'mimeTypes' => [

                            'image/jpeg',

                            'image/png',

                            'image/webp',
                            
                            'image/jpg',

                        ],

                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload une image valide',

                    ]),

                ],

            ])

            ->add('recipeDescription', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Description of the recipe',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Description of the recipe',
                ],
                
            ])
            ->add('duration', NumberType::class, [
                'label' => 'Duration of the recipe',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'The duration of the recipe in minutes',
                ],
            ])

            ->add('difficulty', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Difficulty',
                'placeholder' => 'Difficulty',
                'class' => Difficulty::class,
                'choice_label' => function(Difficulty $difficulty){
                    return strtoupper($difficulty->getDifficultyName());
                }
            ])

            ->add('recipeIngredients', CollectionType::class, [
                //le collection type need a element 'form , entity, ...
                'entry_type' => RecipeIngredientsFormType::class,
                'prototype' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                // we allow adds on persist with the cascade_persist;
                //its gonna be a html and we can manipulate it with js
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,

                'by_reference' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'collection-recipeIngredients',
                ]

            ])

            ->add('steps', CollectionType::class, [
                //le collection type need a element 'form , entity, ...
                'entry_type' => StepsFormType::class,
                'prototype' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                // we allow adds on persist with the cascade_persist;
                //its gonna be a html and we can manipulate it with js
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,

                'by_reference' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'collection-steps',
                ]

            ])
            
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Recipe::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here my StepsFormnType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Steps;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;


class StepsFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('stepDescription', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Description of the step',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Description of the step',
                ],
            ])

            ->add('stepsImage' , FileType::class, [

                'label' => 'Image of the step',

                "attr" => ['class' => "form-control"],

                'mapped' => true,

                'required' => false,

                'constraints' => [

                    new File([

                        'maxSize' => '10254k',

                        'mimeTypes' => [

                            'image/jpeg',

                            'image/png',

                            'image/webp',
                            
                            'image/jpg',

                        ],

                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid image ',

                    ]),

                ],  

            ])
         
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Steps::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and here the JQuery code i use for the collectionType ;

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Une fois que le document (base.html.twig) HTML/CSS a bien été complètement chargé...
    // add-collection-widget.js : fonction permettant d'ajouter un nouveau bloc "programme" au sein d'une question (pour agrandir la collection)
    $('.add-another-collection-widget').click(function (e) {
        let list = $($(this).attr('data-list-selector'))
       
        // Récupération du nombre actuel d'élément "programme" dans la collection (à défaut, utilisation de la longueur de la collection)
        let counter = list.data('widget-counter') || list.children().length
       
        // Récupération de l'identifiant de la question concernée, en cours de création/modification
        let recipe = list.data('recipe')
        console.log(recipe)
        // Extraction du prototype complet du champ (que l'on va adapter ci-dessous)
        let newWidget = list.attr('data-prototype')
        console.log(newWidget)
        // Remplacement des séquences génériques "__name__" utilisées dans les parties "id" et "name" du prototype
        // par un numéro unique au sein de la collection de "programmes" : ce numéro sera la valeur du compteur
        // courant (équivalent à l'index du prochain champ, en cours d'ajout).
        // Au final, l'attribut ressemblera à "question[programmes][n°]"
        newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, counter)
        // Ajout également des attributs personnalisés "class" et "value", qui n'apparaissent pas dans le prototype original 
        newWidget = newWidget.replace(/><input type="hidden"/, ' class="borders"><input type="hidden" value="'+recipe+'"')
        // Incrément du compteur d'éléments et mise à jour de l'attribut correspondant
        counter++
        list.data('widget-counter', counter)
        // Création d'un nouvel élément (avec son bouton de suppression), et ajout à la fin de la liste des éléments existants
        var newElem = $(list.attr('data-widget-tags')).html(newWidget)
        addDeleteLink($(newElem).find('div.borders'))
        newElem.appendTo(list)
    })
    // anonymize-collection-widget.js : fonction permettant de supprimer un bloc "programme" existant au sein d'une question
    $('.remove-collection-widget').find('div.borders').each(function() {
        addDeleteLink($(this))
    })
    // fonction permettant l'ajout d'un bouton "Supprimer ce answer" dans un bloc "programme", et d'enregistrer l'évenement "click" associé
    function addDeleteLink($recipeIngredientsForm) {
        var $removeFormButton = $('<div class="block"><button type="button" class="button">Supprimer</button></div>');
        $recipeIngredientsForm.append($removeFormButton)
    
        $removeFormButton.on('click', function(e) {
            $recipeIngredientsForm.remove()
        })
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

can you do a Scheme of your Controller, I think you have a trouble with this :

```
    foreach($images as $img){
  
    $imgs[] = $img; 

  }
}
```

Any times when your action go inside this, the first index is 0 ..
it's possible to have code with code like this :

```
foreach($images as $key in $value) { $array[$key] = ... }
```

Or use incrémential index, declared at beginning. ( $imgs[$index] = $img;   $index++ ;)

Comment: thanks for your asnwer but may i ask what do you mean about make a Scheme of my Controller?

Comment: an kind of Unified Modeling Language (UML) simplified by exemple, to understand where are issues

Comment: i dont know if you saw but i post an edit on top of the message. And  for the UML mean the recipe has **one or many** steps and the step is related to one recipe.